# negative even coefficients of virtual Poincare polynomials, with odd coefficients vanishing

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be any complex projective (not necessarily smooth) variety. Let $P(X)$ be the virtual Poincare polynomial of $X$ defined by Deligne's mixed Hodge theory, that is,
$$P(X)=\sum_{i,j} (-1)^{i+j} \dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\text{gr}^j_W H^i_{\text{cpt}}(X;\mathbb{Q}) ) t^j,$$
where $\text{gr}^j_W H^i_{\text{cpt}}(X;\mathbb{Q})$ is the $j$-th weight-graded piece of the $i$-th rational 
cohomology group of $X$ with compact supports.

Let $c_j=\sum_{i} (-1)^{i+j} \dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\text{gr}^j_W H^i_{\text{cpt}}(X;\mathbb{Q}) )$, i.e., the coefficient of $t^j$. 
My first question is

(1) Which sequences $(c_0, c_1, ...)$ can arise as sequences of coefficients of virtual Poincare polynomials? If $X$ is non-compact, any sequence might occur, but I'm interested in proper varieties.

This may be very hard. So an easier question is

(2) Is there an example of a projective variety $X$ with $c_1=c_3=c_5=\cdots=0$ and $P(X)|_{t=1}$<0? Smooth projective varieties cannot satisfy both conditions. It seems to me that if such a variety exists, then its desingularization has a badly-behaved exceptional locus.

Thank you for any comments.